# Request sent with version Http/0.9

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache Commons HttpClient v3.1. All my requests are having correct (default) HTTP version in the request line i.e HTTP/1.1 except for 1 request.

Following Post request gets the requestline as HTTP/0.9:

```
server : port/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-1-sUqenNbqUzvkGSWW25lcbaJc0OEcJ6wg5DOj3XDMSwoIBf6s7i-cas-1
Body: service=*
```

I debugged through the http client code and saw the requestline is set to HTTP/1.1 but on the server I see the request coming as HTTP/0.9.

I tried to set the HTTP version explicitly using the `HttpMethodParams` but that does not help.
Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HostConfiguration hc = client.getHostConfiguration();
    hc.setHost(new URI(url, false));

    PostMethod method = new PostMethod();
    method.setURI(new URI(url, false));

    method.getParams().setUriCharset("UTF-8");
    method.getParams().setHttpElementCharset("UTF-8");
    method.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");
    method.getParams().setVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    method.addParameter("service", URLEncoder.encode(service, "UTF-8"));
    method.setPath(contextPath + "/tickets/" + tgt);

    String  respBody = null;
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
    respBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Comment: Sometimes proxies (even transparent ones) do strange things like this. Is the server local to the client? Did you try sniffing at the client end as well?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Joachim Sauer. I was able to figure out the problem.

I was using Webscarab as web proxy and it emitted out following message "Got a continuation header but had no previous header line". Looked it up online and found that the problem was in multi-line requestline. I was setting the HTTP version to 1.1 explicitly however there was a trailing '\r\n' in the url which made the requestline look like Http/0.9.

Difference between Http/0.9 and Http/1.0 or other higher protocols is that 0.9 had a simple requestline 'METHOD URL'. Later versions also include the Http version in the request line 'METHOD URL HTTPVERSION'.

Hope it saves someone day!

Comment: Just a clarification, HTTP/0.9 does not support methods, only the word GET and the document address in the request line.